# Mediawiki: The built-in autocomplete Search feature doesn't work

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have a private wiki where I did an update a few weeks ago.
The current version is MediaWiki 1.39.1
Then I changed the template to Vector (2022), and exactly with the template "The built-in autocomplete feature" doesn't work.
It works with all other templates, but with Vector (2022) it doesn't work.
Does anyone have a tip for me, what I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Which extensions do you have installed?